# List structure size function, difficulty with code

Tags: python, list, python-3.x, flatten

I need to write a function(size) that gets a list structure and recieves its size. The size is the number of pair brackets and the number of ints in the list structure.
For example: size([[[14],[23,[14]]]])= 8   (5 pair brackets, 3 ints)

I wrote a code but I cant find a way that cnt won't assign to zero each time I call the recursion.
This is my code:

```
def flatten(lst):
    if type(lst)==int:
        return [lst]
    elif lst==[]:
        return []
    else:
        return sum(([x] if not isinstance(x, list) else flatten(x) for x in lst),[])

def size(lst):
    cnt=0
    if lst== []:
        return 1
    if type(lst)== int:
        return 1
    b= str(lst)
    ind= b.find('[')
    while ind!=-1:
        cnt+=1
        lst=lst[ind+1:]
        return cnt+ size(lst)
    return cnt+ len(flatten(lst))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do something much simpler, like:

```py
def size(lst):
    if type(lst) == int:
        return 1
    else:
        return 1 + sum(size(e) for e in lst)

print size([[[14],[23,[14]]]])
```